# PL SQL Inserting Parameters into String

Tags: database, string, plsql

I am trying to insert a new row into a table in my database. I am having issues with the MODPLSQL_PROCEDURE_NAME field below.

```
DECLARE
    lId VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    lId := 'XLRP' || SEQ.NEXTVAL;
END;

INSERT INTO REPORTS(CATEGORY_ID, 
                             DESCRIPTION, 
                             ID, 
                             MODPLSQL_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                             MODPLSQL_PROCEDURE_NAME, 
                             NOTES)
            VALUES          ('XLRC0', 
                             'Training Task XL Report', 
                             'XLRP' || WORKFLOW_REPORTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 
                             '!MODPLSQL_XL_REPORTS_PKG', 
                             'XL_REPORT?pReportId=' || lId || '&' || 'pReportName=Training Task XL Report' || '&' || 'pPackageName=TRAINING_PKG' || '&' || 'pProcedureName=RUN_NOW', 
                             NULL);
```

My desired output for the field is shown below (Example lId = XLRP100):

```
XL_REPORT?pReportId=XLRP100&pReportName=Training Task XL Report&pPackageName=TRAINING_PKG&pProcedureName=RUN_NOW
```

In the MODPLSQL_PROCEDURE_NAME I need to import a seq generated ID lId from the statement above. Can anyone advise me on the correct syntax to do this?

Additionally, I have broken up my string with &'s in order to avoid a box popping up requesting me to input paramters, 'set define off' does not change this. Is there a better way of writing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the value of `lId` in your `INSERT` statement, the easiest way is to move it into your PL/SQL block, for example:

```
DECLARE
    lId VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
    lId := 'XLRP' || SEQ.NEXTVAL;

    INSERT INTO REPORTS(CATEGORY_ID, 
                             DESCRIPTION, 
                             ID, 
                             MODPLSQL_PACKAGE_NAME, 
                             MODPLSQL_PROCEDURE_NAME, 
                             NOTES)
            VALUES          ('XLRC0', 
                             'Training Task XL Report', 
                             lId,
                             '!MODPLSQL_XL_REPORTS_PKG', 
                             'XL_REPORT?pReportId=' || lId || '&' || 'pReportName=Training Task XL Report' || '&' || 'pPackageName=TRAINING_PKG' || '&' || 'pProcedureName=RUN_NOW', 
                             NULL);

END;
```

Secondly, if you want to avoid any problems with the `&` character, you can use `CHR(38)` instead.

```
                             'XL_REPORT?pReportId=' || lId || CHR(38) || 'pReportName=Training Task XL Report' || CHR(38) || 'pPackageName=TRAINING_PKG' || CHR(38) || 'pProcedureName=RUN_NOW',
```